# Is a gun in the waistband with a tucked-in shirt concealed or open carry in Michigan?

Tags: united-states, firearms, michigan, weapons

I generally carry my gun concealed, inside the waistband with a shirt or jacket over it. If I were to tuck said shirt in, the grip will show.

Is this now considered open carry, or does the whole gun have to be showing?

Comment: Legally speaking, this is an interesting question.  Non-legally speaking, [this is a bad idea](https://www.outdoorhub.com/stories/2015/07/27/concealed-carry-myths-dont-need-holster/).

Comment: @RyanM What makes you think a holster isnt being used? In waistband holsters are quite common, maybe even the most common type of holster used by people carrying concealed.

Answer (score 3):

It will hinge on the specific facts, but if the pistol is not *discernible* by *casual observation* it will most likely be regarded as concealed.

Michigan Open Carry Inc's [FAQ #11](https://miopencarry.org/faq#11) asks:

> **Can I open carry with an inside the waistband/inside the pants (IWB) holster?**
>
> The Michigan Court of Appeals appears to answer this in [People v
> Curtis Phillips (1996)](http://publicdocs.courts.mi.gov:81/Opinions/Final/COA/19960830_C185231(0027)_185231.OPN.PDF) (unpublished):
>
> In the case, officers observed Mr. Phillips standing on a nearby porch
> with the butt of a gun protruding out of his waistband. **The Court held
> that the pistol was not visible under "ordinary observation” and
> therefore "A casual observer may not have discerned the object in
> defendant’s waistband."**
>
> Essentially, it's up to the "trier of fact", meaning open to
> interpretation for a judge in a bench trial, or a jury in a jury
> trial.

The FAQ goes on to quote The Michigan Court of Appeals *per curiam* in People v Curtis Phillips (1996)

> Defendant argues that the evidence was insufficient to prove beyond a
> reasonable doubt that he “concealed” a handgun because the arresting
> officers could see the butt of a gun protruding from his waistband. We
> disagree.
>
> To determine whether a rational trier of fact could have found that
> the essential elements of the crime were proven beyond a reasonable
> doubt, this Court views the evidence in the light most favorable to
> the prosecution. People v Wolfe, 440 Mich 508, 515; 489 NW2d 748
> (1992). A conviction for carrying a concealed weapon without a license
> requires proof that the accused concealed a dangerous weapon. People v
> Pickett, 21 Mich App 246, 248; 175 NW2d 347 (1970). **Concealment is a
> question of fact and exists when the weapon is “not discernible by the
> ordinary observation of [those] coming in contact with [the accused],
> casually observing him, as people do in the ordinary and usual
> associations of life.”** [People v Johnnie W Jones, 12 Mich App 293, 296;
> 162 NW2d 847 (1968).](http://www.leagle.com/decision/196830512MichApp293_1269/PEOPLE%20v.%20JOHNNIE%20W.%20JONES)
>
> While searching the area for gunmen after a reported shooting, the
> arresting officers observed defendant standing on a nearby porch with
> the butt of a handgun protruding from his waistband. They were able to
> identify this object as the butt of a handgun based on their training
> and experience. The officers were not “casually observing” defendant
> “in the ordinary and usual associations of life,” and this was not
> “ordinary observation” because the officers were searching for armed
> suspects. A casual observer may not have discerned the object in
> defendant’s waistband. Therefore, viewing the evidence in the light
> most favorable to the prosecution, a rational trier of fact could
> conclude there was sufficient evidence that defendant concealed a gun
> in his waistband.